# Order of oracle sql queries execution

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I'm very new to Oracle. And I have a table and some queries here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7b7c/1

I wonder how the query:

```
select distinct name,id from test;
```

and

```
select name,id from test group by name,id;
```

producing the *same* output. How in oracle I can find the order in which the above query's get executed? Its random for every data? Or there is a way in which it will execute for all the datasets.

Answer (score 1):

typically if you want to debug performance you'd use an explain plan like so:

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, ID 
FROM TEST;

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT NAME, ID 
FROM TEST 
GROUP BY (NAME,ID);

that will show you what sort of processing the query optimiser thinks is the best, you can't guarantee you will always get the same plan, eg if you add indexes the plan may change, you can use hints but I don't think I've seen them actually being used

Answer (score 1):

The reason all queries produce the same results is because the table has unique values.

Using "group by" is in this case makes no sense.  Use "group by" when you want to count or sum (or other mathematical operations).  Here is such an example:

```
select name, count(*) ct from test group by name
```

This will show the name and how many times the name appears in the table.

Regarding the order of the output:  Oracle will return the rows in a random order until instructed.  So to specify a particular order, then use the "order by" clause as:

```
select name,id from test order by name, id;
```

Then you are guaranteed that results will be returned sorted by name.  And if the name shows up more than once, they will be order by id.

Answer (score 1):

> How in oracle I can find the order in which the above query's get executed? Its random for every data? Or there is a way in which it will execute for all the datasets.

In SQL, the order in which rows are determined is *unspecified* unless you ask for one explicitly using an `order by` clause. (If not, you'll get rows in the order in which they're found to match your query, and which they are will depend on the query plan.)

> [the queries are] producing the *same* output.

This is because you've the id in there. Presumably, they're all distinct and marked as the primary key in your actual schema.

`distinct`, btw, is a `group by` all retrieved fields for all intents and purposes.

Anyway, if you want the rows in order consistently, you want something like `order by name, id`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your SQL Fiddle: you have five records in your table, with five combinations of NAME and ID.  So the queries you posted are just going to return all rows.  Effectively they are the same as this query ...

```
select name, id from test;
```

... only with extra resource consumption for the nugatory sorts the database undertakes to ensure uniqueness.  Adding a new record which duplicates the NAME and ID but has a different EMAIL will help you understand what's going on.

You should understand that using DISTINCT is actually quite rare in real life: a properly defined WHERE clause should suffice to generate a unique result set.  GROUP BY is normally used with a aggregating function like COUNT() or SUM(); for instance, how many NAME + IDs have more than one EMAIL?

```
select name, id from test 
group by name, id having count(*) > 1;
```

As for ordering, your executed queries require sorts so the order of the result set may differ from the input order.  Oracle does not guarantee the order of its result sets anyway, but sorting makes it even less predictable.  To get that guarantee it is necessary to specify an ORDER BY clause:

```
select distinct name, id from test 
order by name, id
```

That ORDER BY clause will guarantee the same order for any statement, regardless of what other processing occurs when filtering and process the result set.